# Create a random, sine graph like landscape sprite

Tags: android, box2d, sprite, andengine

Lets say I have this sprite:

[image: Sample sprite]

And I created a random landscape during runtime:

[image: Dynamic runtime landscape]

And then, I want to tile the area below the line with the sprite:

[image]

This is the game ground, *therefore it should also be a physics object (In Box2D)*.

[Here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post21928.html), he given a sample of how to make this a physics body. So, how do I do the graphics part in code?

**EDIT:** Looking in the AndEngine examples, file [RepeatingSpriteBackgroundExample.java](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/RepeatingSpriteBackgroundExample.java), it's not exactly what I need but should I stick to this idea and change the [RepeatingSpriteBackground class](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/scene/background/RepeatingSpriteBackground.java) for my needs? I don't think that would be the best method however...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I don't really know about Box2D or AndEngine, but I thought this was an interesting problem and made a custom SurfaceView that can draw a random "terrain" like the one in your picture. (Hopefully it will be of use to you or someone else, at least I learnt some new stuff :p)
Single colour terrain:
[image: screenshot]
Tiled background-terrain:
[image: screenshot]
The tiled bitmap:
[image: resource bitmap]

My code is as follows:

```
public class PathView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private class DrawingRunnable implements Runnable{
    private final static int minPointsOnScreen = 3;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Random rand = new Random();

    private Path path;
    private Paint pathPaint;
    Bitmap background;
    private Paint tilePaint;        

    volatile boolean running = false;

    int width;
    int height;
    int maxHeight;

    protected DrawingRunnable(SurfaceHolder sh){
        surfaceHolder = sh;

        pathPaint = new Paint();
        pathPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        pathPaint.setStrokeWidth(4);

        tilePaint = new Paint();
    }

    protected void createPath(){
        path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.WINDING);

        path.setLastPoint(0, height);
        int lastX = 0, lastY = height - rand.nextInt(maxHeight);
        path.lineTo(lastX,lastY);

        int newX=lastX, newY=lastY;

        do{ 
            lastX = newX; lastY = newY;
            newX += rand.nextInt(width/minPointsOnScreen);
            newY = height - rand.nextInt(maxHeight);
            path.cubicTo(
                    interpolateLinear(lastX, newX, 0.333f),
                    lastY,
                    interpolateLinear(lastX, newX, 0.666f),
                    newY,
                    newX, newY);
        }while(newX <= width);

        path.lineTo(width, height);
    }

    private int interpolateLinear(int start, int end, float part){
        return (int) (start*(1-part) + end*part);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(running){
            Canvas c = null;
            try{
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) { 
                    doDraw(c); 
                }
            } finally{ if(c!=null) surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); }
            SystemClock.sleep(40);
        }
    }

    private void doDraw(Canvas c){
        c.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        //c.drawPath(path, pathPaint); //Use this to draw a single-colour. (First screenshot)
        c.clipPath(path);
        for(int y = 0; y+background.getHeight() < height+background.getHeight(); y+=background.getHeight()){
            for(int x = 0; x+background.getWidth() < width+background.getWidth(); x+=background.getWidth()){
                c.drawBitmap(background, x, y, tilePaint);
            }
        }
    }
}

private ExecutorService exec;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private DrawingRunnable drawer;

public PathView(Context c){ super(c); init(c); }
public PathView(Context c, AttributeSet as){ super(c, as); init(c); }
public PathView(Context c, AttributeSet as, int defStyle){ super(c, as, defStyle); init(c); }

private void init(Context c){
    exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sh){
    if( drawer == null ){
        drawer = new DrawingRunnable(holder);
        drawer.width = getWidth();
        drawer.height = getHeight();
        drawer.maxHeight = drawer.height/2;
        drawer.createPath();
        drawer.background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tile);
    }
    drawer.running = true;
    exec.execute(drawer);
}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder sh){
    drawer.running = false;
}
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder sh, int format, int width, int height){}
}
```

If this is of any help to you you'll probably have to play around with the parameters to get shapes that suits your needs and most likely add a parameter for minimum distance between points etc.
It is also a good idea to optimize the drawing of the background a bit, like drawing from the bottom up to the maximum height of the terrain, to minimize drawing to invisible areas. I should also be possible to reduce the amount of calls to getHeight() and getWidth().

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but its not exactly what I needed. First of all, AndEngine uses its own version of SurfaceView (although I guess I could subclass it too). But I need to find out how do I tile the landscape with a square texture, the algorithms for creating paths are the easier part :(

Comment: I changed the doDraw() a bit to do this in case it is of any help to you :)

Comment: It works great, but I can't use these native android classes when developing with AndEngine - I need to use AndEngine classes. However, I'll have a look if I can combine them both... (Your SurfaceView and AndEngine's SurfaceView)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. But then again it might be of help to someone else, or maybe at least give some ideas for a solution to your problem. Nevertheless, it was fun to do :)

Comment: Well, looks like it can't be done with AndEngine. Although your answer didn't help me, it was very good so I'll award you the bounty :)

Comment: Thank you. I enjoyed creating the 'solution' :)