# Implementing a tiling system in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm a bit stumped on an Android game I am developing, so maybe someone can help me. Don't bother suggesting AndEngine; I've made it this far on my own and I'd prefer to continue on this path if possible.

The game I'm working on is a simple platformer. Originally the levels were loaded as massive bitmaps, but a few out of memory errors made it obvious that I had to come up with a more efficient system. Now I'm parsing out .tmx files into a 2d array and using a method that creates a bitmap slightly bigger than the device's screen and fills it with the appropriate tiles.

The issue is that accessing this 2d array 1500 times (using 16x16 tiles) is very expensive, and I'm having trouble figuring out a way to not do that so much. Currently I'm having to redraw the image every time I pass over 16 pixels. Current ideas include using larger tiles (smaller array, still limits level size though), attempting to shift the contents of my bitmap and only load in the new row about to be displayed, or using a larger bitmap so that new images don't need to be loaded as often. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

*Unless already done or impossible*; consider separating the background from the foreground.
If you use a simple background (think Super Mario plain blue backgrounds) then you can most likely reuse those tiles/that bitmap/color/gradient much longer than the foreground elements.
This will also make your array/s contain lots of empty spaces where no foreground exists, meaning you could collapse the array and only store the parts containing tiles. Collapsing the arrays will come with the drawback that you will have to store a height attribute for the tiles to know where they are supposed to go.
(A background separate from the foreground also give the possibility of parallax-effects (background moving in different speed than foreground))

**An example of how this changes your lookup:**
Consider the game is being run on a 480x800 screen in landscape-mode.
This means 50*30 (1500) tiles to look up.
Every tile is saved in a 2d-array.
The current visible area looks like this:

- A ground area, 4 tiles high.
- A platform, 5 tiles high and 20 tiles wide, somewhere above the ground.
- Another platform 3 tiles high and 5 tiles wide, also above ground.
- A wall extending from the ground to the top of the screen, 5 tiles wide.

Removing the background tiles and collapsing the arrays we only have to look up the tiles:
Ground tiles: 50*4
Platform1 tiles: 5*20
Platform2 tiles: 3*5
Wall tiles: 26*5
**Total lookups:** 50*4 + 5*20 + 3*5 + 26*5 = 445 which is less than a third of the original 1500.
Now, of course there is some extra work to be done to figure out the position of each tile and drawing the background, but assuming a badly optimized case where this takes as much time as the lookup it is still less time than 1000 lookups.

*Of course, this is just one of possibly many approaches to the problem.*

**Also remember small things like that 2d arrays are much slower than 'flat' arrays**. If you cannot put the data in a 1d-array, try to minimize the nested calls, e.g. get one row or column at a time and perform the lookups from that array before switching to the next:

```
//Really bad:
for(int x=0; x<array.length; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<array[x].length; y++){
        Object o = array[x][y];
    }
}
//Better (can be made even better by using the for(Object o : array)-syntax):
for(int x=0; x<array.length; x++){
    Object[] yArray = array[x];
    for(int y=0; y<yArray.length; y++){
        Object o = yArray[y];
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually do have the background and foreground separated, but the array isn't collapsed in any way so it still results in checking 1500 array entries. Many are found to be empty and no tile is drawn, but as you said it looks like the 2d array is very slow to access. I'm working with Tiled which outputs in .tmx files, and a .tmx parser I found for android that makes the 2d array and contains the painfully slow method for creating a bitmap from it.

Comment: You could, possibly, recreate the 2d array yourself to make it a 1d-array, or modify it in other ways. Also, there shouldn't be a need to create one large bitmap all the time, just draw the bitmaps for each tile instead.

Comment: Wouldn't drawing each tile as a separate bitmap incur a lot of overhead from the garbage collector? I hear it's not overly fast

Comment: If you use indexed tiles - i.e. have one loaded tile of each kind, and only reference them when drawing - the garbage collector shouldn't be a problem, as you will keep the same (few) bitmaps for a long period. But you will have to optimize the drawing so that you don't redraw the entire screen for each bitmap, but just that part of the screen.

Comment: Interesting..would be rough to implement at this point though, I'm a novice programmer and have already reworked the tiling system more than I care to admit. It seems like it would be hugely efficient to just load in rows of tiles as I need them, but I can't find much about shifting bitmaps without using a second full size bitmap to do it..

Comment: Heh, it is always annoying to rewrite code you have already rewritten, but quite satisfying at the end if it turns out better ;)  
Anyways, I imagine that in your case you use a canvas on which you call one of the drawBitmap() methods. If so, you can move the bitmaps around by simply offsetting the parameters. You can take a look at my answer at the following question, it is not exactly what you want, and can most certainly be optimized, but it is about drawing tiles on canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298477/create-a-random-sine-graph-like-landscape-sprite/8340394#8340394

Answer (score 0):

I had to develop this project where we needed to download tiles of image from the web and display them as one whole image. The thing was a casual scroll would end up crashing the entire app because the VM would throw a OutOfMemory Exception. So I developed a view using a TwoDScrollView and MxN ImageViews, which downloaded only those views which were in the users view. As the user scrolls, we maintain a cache and start de allocating images that are "far" away from the viewing region. It was slower but it stopped crashing.

I won't be able to share my part of the code. But here's a Github repo that uses the same approach. Good Luck :)

I can't vouch for them but [here's a project](https://github.com/ened/Android-Tiling-ScrollView) specifically fits your needs