# Parallax background ground line (track) editor

Tags: android, andengine, parallax

I want to create game similiar to that:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fingersoft.hillclimb

My problem is how to manage "ground" layer, or "track layer" in other words.

How to describe it - I consider some kind of definition file (XML/JSON/CSV whatever...) with array of ground points (x,y) for flow description and placement of active elements - have you any experience with that?

Are there any tools for quick design (like TMX editors) - everything better than Vi will good.

Comment: I asked once a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298477/create-a-random-sine-graph-like-landscape-sprite Apparently it can't be done with the regular AndEngine classes. Now that you mentioned TMX it appears possible, you should try. Describe the landscape with a set of ground points, yes.

Comment: Thanks for posting your question.

Comment: The solution will require using OpenGL "native" calls. I might decide to create it in the future, in which case I'll post my final code in this question.